# Compare two result set to find if value lies between min and max

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a complex query which is giving me this result

```
Area  MinValue  MaxValue
A      12.34     34.45
B      34.23     41.23
C      10.23     15.12
```

Now, from another table I am taking count for each area

```
Area  Count
A     24
B     50
C     15
D     22
```

I have to compare these two result sets to find out which area count is not falling between minvalue and maxvalue.

Expected Result set:

```
Area MinValue MaxValue CurrentValue 
B    34.23     41.23      50
```

Comment: Is BETWEEN inclusive or exclusive? If MAX were 50.0, would the B row still be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first join your two result sets on `Area` and then filter for your result.

```
SELECT a.[Area], a.[MinValue], a.[MaxValue], b.[Count] AS CurrentValue
FROM [complexQueryTable] a
JOIN [anotherTable] b
    ON b.[Area] = a.[Area]
WHERE b.[Count] NOT BETWEEN a.[MinValue] AND a.[MaxValue]
```

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b36fd/1)

```
| AREA | MINVALUE | MAXVALUE | CURRENTVALUE |
---------------------------------------------
|    B |       34 |       41 |           50 |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
     QueryB.Area,
     QueryA.MinValue,
     QueryA.MaxValue,
     QueryB.Count AS CurrentValue
FROM ( /* Your first query */ ) QueryA
JOIN ( /* Your second query */) QueryB ON QueryA.Area = QueryB.Area
WHERE QueryB.Count NOT BETWEEN QueryA.MinValue AND QueryB.MaxValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    SELECT T1.Area, MinValue, MaxValue, Count AS CurrentValue
    FROM Table1 T1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
    ON T1.Area=T2.Area
    WHERE Count < MinValue AND Count > MaxValue
```